# How to build modify or build Custom CallKit UI in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, callkit

Using the [flutter_callkit_incoming](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_callkit_incoming) package we can set up a flutter callkit ui, but I'm finding it hard to change the default incoming call UI to something else (i.e. i want to add more widgets).

How it is:

[image]

How I'm trying it to make:

[image]

Is it possible somehow? If not, please provide any other solutions.

I have tried to make a scaffold page on call, but I'm not able to implement the call notification heads up with the ringtone.